# Is "competition" plural or singular?

Tags: idioms, expressions

I was reading through a submitted work by some editor, and I stumbled upon this phrase added...

"a little friendly competition never hurt anyone"

...and I was confused at first of why isn't the word "hurt" "hurts" since competition I thought was singular here.

Am I missing something? Is this some sort of idiom expression where it's always "hurt."

I did trying doing some search but there is no information on the origin of this being a possible adage/idiom.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very common idiom, and it utilizes past tense. That's why the word is "hurt" and not "hurts". The idea is that something has never hurt anyone in the past, so there's no reason to avoid it now.

Comment: Wow thanks Scott! But if you were to use this outside of being an idiom...would it be considered wrong/unacceptable if "hurt" was "hurts" because frankly for somebody like myself who has never thought of this being an idiom might want to write it as an everyday normal sentence following standard grammar of using "hurts" for the singular "competition"? (For example, for a job application, technical writing, academic writing, etc.)

Comment: Competition here is not singular, but non-count. The past tense is necessary. A little competition never hurt anyone (never did anyone any harm).

Comment: Technically it would be just fine to write the sentence in the present tense. A little competition does not hurt anybody -- that makes perfect sense. But understand that the version we're talking about is also grammatically correct. Consider: My brother never hurt me. It's the same basic sentence; I simply replaced a couple of nouns.

Comment: "hurts" is entirely grammatical, but carries a slightly different meaning. With "hurt" the claim is that friendly competition *has* never hurt anyone (in the past); with "hurts" it is that friendly competition *doesn't* hurt anyone (in the present).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that instead of the verb *hurt*, we used the verb *kill*. The sentence would then read (ceteris paribus): *A little friendly competition never killed anyone*. In your sentence, *hurt* is actually the preterit form, and it's equivalent to the present tense plain form. This phenomenon is called [syncretism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncretism_(linguistics)); there's syncretism between the present tense plain form (as opposed to the third person singular one) and preterit of *hurt*. With *kill* we have a distinct present tense plain form (*I/you/we/they kill*) and preterit *killed*.

(Of course, *A little friendly competition never hurts anyone* is also possible and grammatical (although not that commonly heard), and substituting *kill* there renders it as follows: *A little friendly competition never kills anyone*. However, it would be ungrammatical to write **A little friendly competition never kill anyone*, so we may conclude that the *hurt* in the original (grammatical) utterance isn't a present tense plain form (by virtue of the previous utterance's being ungrammatical with that form); it, therefore, has to be something else.)

<sub>(transcribed from comment)</sub>